# Is there any templates collection (HTML+CSS) for ASP.NET MVC3 Views?

Tags: html, css, templates, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering whether exists a set of **templates** to be used in (potentially) any MVC View. I mean a set of predefined **HTML tags (maybe just DIVs, palying as wrappers)** with **id** and **class** attributes, among others, that in combination with CSS renders a complete web page. For example the template shipped with ASP.NET MVC3 in VS2010.
You can then pick up a specific template (i.e. one with a table in the center of the page instead of an image) and built your application behind.

I need this because I absolutely hate CSS (or better their application on HTML) because I never get the size and position that I want!

Thanks in advance

Francesco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/

Steps to loving CSS:

```
div.myClass { width: 30px; margin: 2px 0 0 4px; }
div.myClass ul { list-style: none; }
```

1. Write it neater, like the above:
2. Debug/Develop only in Google Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.  Use the brilliant built in CSS editor/debugger in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.
3. Only use standards-compliant CSS.  This is not because I'm a standards junkie, but because this way it's easier to find help in the CSS/HTML community.
4. When the project is nearing a milestone, look at it in whatever version of IE you need and add a CSS to fix any issues you encounter: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: thanks for the link and the heads up. I indeed agree that CSS are a powerful way to separate styling from behavior but I just hate to fix elements in my HTML code, especially the position and size...HTML do not follow any logic and I was never an artistic guy if you know what I mean :-D Moreover most of the users I deal with use IE...nothing more to add I guess